# owc replacement

Tags: activex

I use OWC  (Office Web Components) v10.0 to embed Excel grid in an asp.net page. Is there a replacement technology where excel grid can be embedded in the client side browser?

Comment: Dear Ajit ! Did you find a suitable replacement for OWC ? I am desparately looking for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like there is one.

http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/silverlight/infragistics-excel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Sharepoint Server, Microsoft offers something called Excel Services, which basically provides spreadsheet functionality in a browser, without requiring an actual component to be deployed (with the Excel work being done on the SPPS server. Info is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms546696.aspx

I know there is an OpenSource product called WikiCalc which is a client-side, spreadsheet component which works in the browser (from Dan Bricklin's company). Some info is here:

http://www.softwaregarden.com/products/wikicalc/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Excel Services is read only. WikiCalc is pearl solution that i am afraid to use in .Net solution.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no .Net solution for client browser excel grid than OWC. Looks like SharePoint 2010 has Office Web Applications that allows Google Docs like spreadsheet functionality in browser. Would evaluate that.